# Query to show all supported column data types

Tags: mysql

Is there an INFORMATION_SCHEMA (or other) query that can display the list of all supported column data types?

eg something that will return CHAR, NVARCHAR, TINYTEXT, TINYINT, SMALLINT etc. etc.

Comment: why you need something like that? Cant you read the manual?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html use this

Comment: Creating a stored-proc to add a column to a table if it doesn't already exist with column type as a string parameter I use to build up a dynamic SQL string and want to validate the parameter against a list of known types rather than hardcode the list. Plus I'm curious if it can be done

Answer (score 2):

you can get all used data type from mysql using following query but it will not give all data types this is not the complete answer for this but added as answer just to get the format

```
mysql> SELECT distinct data_type  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
+------------+
| data_type  |
+------------+
| varchar    |
| bigint     |
| longtext   |
| datetime   |
| int        |
| tinyint    |
| decimal    |
| double     |
| date       |
| text       |
| mediumtext |
| timestamp  |
| mediumblob |
| smallint   |
| enum       |
| time       |
| char       |
| blob       |
| set        |
| longblob   |
| float      |
+------------+
21 rows in set, 1 warning (0.06 sec)
```